# Create list from objects in Python

Tags: python

I'm having troubles creating a list from the numbers I made using my code.

```
ListA = [5,1,3,8,4]

LengthB = (len(ListA))


obj0 = ListA[0]
obj1 = ListA[1]
obj2 = ListA[2]
obj3 = ListA[3]
obj4 = ListA[4]

obj01 = int(obj0)
obj11 = int(obj1)
obj21 = int(obj2)
obj31 = int(obj3)
obj41 = int(obj4)

obj010 = obj01+obj11
obj110 = obj01+obj11+obj21
obj210 = obj11+obj21+obj31
obj310 = obj21+obj31+obj41
obj410 = obj31+obj41

ListBnum0 = (obj010 / 2)
ListBnum1 = obj110 / 3
ListBnum2 = obj210 / 3
ListBnum3 = obj310/ 3
ListBnum4 = obj410 / 2


print(ListBnum0)
print(ListBnum1)
print(ListBnum2)
print(ListBnum3)
print(ListBnum4)

FinalForm1 = str(ListBnum0)
FinalForm2 = str(ListBnum1)
FinalForm3 = str(ListBnum2)
FinalForm4 = str(ListBnum3)
FinalForm5 = str(ListBnum4)
```

Basically this program takes the `ListA` numbers and computes the average of the one behind the number, the number and number after if applicable. My real question is how can I take either `ListBnum(0)` to `ListBnum(4)` and create another list out of the numbers?

Why does this return an error below?

```
ListB = list[ListBnum0,ListBnum1,ListBnum2,ListBnum3,ListBnum4]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is:

```
new_list = [ListBnum0, ListBnum1, ListBnum2, ListBnum3, ListBnum4]
```

The reason you get an error when doing this:

```
ListB = list[ListBnum0,ListBnum1,ListBnum2,ListBnum3,ListBnum4]
```

… is that `list` is a function, and function calls need parentheses to call them. You could write it like this:

```
ListB = list([ListBnum0,ListBnum1,ListBnum2,ListBnum3,ListBnum4])
```

However, there's no reason to do so. What the `list` function does is to take any iterable as an argument, and return a list with the same values. But `[ListBnum0, …]` is *already* a list, so you're just making a copy for no reason.

---

Meanwhile, this whole design is clunky. Better to process the whole list at a time, than to split it into 5 separate variables and process them one by one and merge them back into a list. For example:

```
ListA = [5,1,3,8,4]
List0 = [int(i) for i in ListA]
def avg(x):
    return sum(x) / len(x)
ListB = [avg(List0[max(i-1, 0):i+2]) for i in range(len(List0))]
ListFinal = [str(i) for i in ListB]
```

Comment: yeah i know this was very sloppy to do but it made it easier for getting my result since this is the best way i could break it down in my head. im planning on redoing the list, but if i cant remake the program right i want a default to ensure i have the right answer. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Also how would you change the design to process it all at once?